# How to find an editor to my poems?

Tags: editing, poetry

I have written some poems, is there a way to get them edited before I send them to publish. What services can be preferred for editing by a Publishing Company?

Comment: If you are looking at a hybrid publisher, expect to pay for the editing service. In any case, you should have your poems as polished as you can before submitting them to a publisher. A good critique group can make a world of difference. I know you didn't ask about critique groups, but I suggest you look into one. Also, unless you find a hybrid publisher that is used to doing poetry, don't expect great edits. Someone used to editing prose may not have the right skill set for editing poetry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with the hybrid publishing agencies, they usually along with Publishing guidance also help you with the editing.
It would depend on the package that you choose with them and how much in depth you would want them to assist. 
Some of the additional help you might need with them:

- Basic flow/alignment of your poems
- Formatting the content based on your book dimensions
- Illustrations/Book Cover Design
- Marketing/Sales

If you are not seeking any professional help, best and simple way out could be someone from the Writing Community you know who might help you out with Editing with just "Editor: Credits" without any monetary returns.